# Can I change the order of IP addresses in Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, ip, iproute

I'm running into some networking issues that seem to be related to the order of IP addresses, as displayed in iproute2. This is what it normally looks like:

```
# ip -4 -o address show dev eth0
2: eth0    inet 192.168.222.212/23 brd 192.168.223.255 scope global eth0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0    inet 169.254.0.2/24 scope global eth0:0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0    inet 169.254.1.2/24 scope global eth0:1\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, I'm experiencing a strange event on the network that causes the main IP to get flushed/re-added, which makes it show up at the bottom of the list:

```
# ip -4 -o address show dev eth0
2: eth0    inet 169.254.0.2/24 scope global eth0:0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0    inet 169.254.1.2/24 scope global eth0:1\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0    inet 192.168.222.212/23 brd 192.168.223.255 scope global eth0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As a result, in this situation my outgoing IGMP packets now come from 169.254.0.2, instead of 192.168.222.212 until I reboot or flush the entire interface and re-add the IPs.

Is there a way I can force newly created IPs to appear at the top of the list? Do I need to patch the kernel to make this happen?

Comment: Sorry, I  have no time but http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-saddr-selection.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, taking a read through.  

I don't understand however, the route seems correct, but the packets are still coming out the wrong IP:  

    # ip route get 224/4  
    multicast 224.0.0.0 dev eth0 src 192.168.222.212   
        cache <mc>

Comment: *As a result, in this situation my outgoing IGMP packets now come from 169.254.0.2, instead of 192.168.222.212 until I reboot or flush the entire interface and re-add the IPs.* You cant ping from one subnet to another sbunet without packet forwarding. ***How do you get the idea that you send pings with 169.254. while 192.168 is connected to the internet?**  `sudo ip route` will show you your default route to the internet

Comment: I reproduced everything OP told. IGMP (not ICMP, didn't check) are sent from the "wrong" address.

Comment: Right, this is multicast specific. Using `tcpdump -i eth0 -nv igmp` (or wireshark), I can see multicast queries come in to 224.0.0.1. Then the aliased IP 169.254.0.2 will respond to the query. This also shows up on the logs of the router itself. If I delete/re-add the 169 IPs, then the main address 192.168.222.212 will be at the top of the list and outgoing IGMP packets will be stamped with its address again. So far specifying `src` in iproute & iptables have not helped me, neither has opening sockets with `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` to bind it to the IP I want.

Comment: Example command to reproduce this within a similar setup: `socat udp4-recvfrom:6666,ip-add-membership=239.255.1.1:192.168.222.212:eth0 -`

Comment: Can you tell me the `ip route show type multicast` output?

Comment: The command returns nothing, I guess there are no multicast routes set up? It also seems the kernel I'm using does not come with multicast routing, I will need to add the module. I get this when running ip mroute: `Non multicast route received, kernel does support IP multicast? Dump terminated.`

Comment: My kernel does support multicast (any kernel sending IGMP is supposed to support multicast anyway) and even adding `ip route add multicast 224.0.0.0/4 dev eth0 src 192.168.222.212` doesn't help. `ip route get 239.255.1.1`  gets `src 192.168.222.212` and `<mc>` flag, but IGMP is still sent from first address 169.254.0.2 . The easiest to be convinced is to reproduce it.

Comment: Your eth0 aliased. Can you set up the eth0:0 (or similar) to the IP you need and in the ip route use the eth0:0 device?

Comment: ip routing has not helped much...
I've also just tried using SNAT to re-stamp outgoing packets, with no luck: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 169.254.0.2/16 -d 224.0.0.22/4 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.222.212`

Answer (score 1):

After much trials & tribulations, the main issue has been identified.

The problem was the scope of IP addresses. The two internal addresses (169.254.x.x) were set up with a scope of global. Changing the scope to **host** resolved the issue.